# In the simplest terms, what is the difference between synchronize to repository and update to HEAD?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, repository, synchronize

I have seen the question answered on this and other sites, but in terms that only left me more confused. I often encounter an issue where I'm trying to commit code but am told that my file(s) is out of date and I never know which of those two things I'm supposed to do first. On top of that, it seems that synchronize with repository will often delete things in my files which I don't want it to do; I only want to import additions (added lines to files or new files altogether) and changes from the repository, I don't want anything deleted from my files. Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

> with repository will often delete things in my files which I don't want it to do

Running `svn update` does not delete files with local modifications. Therefore, it is unclear what kind of issue you are asking about.

Comment: Delete things in my files, not delete the files altogether. Like if I want to merge my local files with the latest version of the repository what do I do for that? When I have tried synchronize with repository, it will just replace my files with what is on the repository, which effectively erases any changes I have made on my local files.

Comment: @thp94 subversion never deletes any content. never. If there was some issue, describe it in detail.

Comment: That's about as detailed as I can get; I had specified "in the simplest terms" in the question because this is all new information to me. I don't know what "subversion" or "svn update" refer to, hence the request for simple explanations. I'm assuming at this point that I'm misusing terms but the original point of my question was to get clarification on how to commit my own code and keep mine up to date with the latest revisions available on a repository.